# Express.io, socket.io.js not found

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I got an issue with Express.io, I try to create a simple tchat. But I'm not be able to include the socket.io.js, I got an error...

I just installed Express.io on my new Express project.

My errors :

1. GET http://*********/socket.io/socket.io.js 404 (Not Found)
2. localhost:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined

**Index.jade**

```
doctype 5
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
    block content
    script(src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js")
    script(src="/javascripts/user.js")
```

**app.js**

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express.io')
    , index = require('./routes/index.js')
    , http = require('http')
    , path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.http().io();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.get('/', index.index);

app.io.route('ready', function(req) {
    req.io.emit('talk', {
        message: 'io event from an io route on the server'
    });
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

**index.js (route)**

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'TCHAT'
    });
};
```

**user.js**

```
io = io.connect();

// Emit ready event.
io.emit('ready');

// Listen for the talk event.
io.on('talk', function(data) {
    alert(data.message);
});
```

**New error**

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://*****:3000/socket.io.js
Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined

Comment: What's your node version?  While trying to replicate I got an npm install error during socket.io-client on node 0.6.18 which could explain things if you're on 0.6.x

Comment: Try including `socket.io.js` from root, as you're doing with `user.js`: `script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")`.

Comment: Nearly the same thing... See above. (new error)

Comment: I don't understand what I'm supposed to do ?! Remove socket.io ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dude, you are listening on `http` server not `express.io` server. Change this

```
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

to this :

```
app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
   console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

then you will be able to access `socket.io.js`

Comment: @JonathanLonowski yes that is true for Express 3.x, but in express.io, you listen to both http and socket.io, which is why he cannot access socket.io server/functions

Comment: Ah. Yep. Missed that it redefined `app.listen()` to use `app.server.listen(...)` instead.